# Autofilter is not taking range above 100 rows to delete the filtered data

Tags: excel, vba

'1. Apply Filter

`ws.Range("A3:W100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Exported", "Rejected", "MarkedRejected", "Completed"), Operator:=xlFilterValues`

`

'2. Delete Rows

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ws.Range("A3:W100").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

'3. Clear Filter

```
On Error Resume Next
ws.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: 100 rows? How? I can see only 97 rows

Comment: Note that it cannot delete any rows *"above"* 100 because you limit the filter and delete to 100 `ws.Range("A3:W100").AutoFilter`. Adjust your range `A3:W100` to cover all your data instead only to 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could make your code flexible to consider as many rows as column A not empty values

```
With ws
    With .Range("A3:W" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Exported", "Rejected", "MarkedRejected", "Completed"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: Additionally I recommend to test if `Not  …SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) Is Nothing`  before `.Delete` otherwise it throws an exception if the filter did not find anythting. Eg. you run the code twice it will fail the second time.